# SQL Between Function Isn't Getting All Data It Should Get

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms

There is a standard query to pull information from a table.

I am using the between function to pull data from a specific date range.
But there is a problem. Let's say the date range is 2023-6-1 and 2023-6-30

I should be able to pull all data that has that date range but instead I am missing the dates from 2023-6-5 to 2023-6-10 and 2023-6-25 to 2023-6-27

But that data is there originally in the table and I am not sure why I cannot pull that date range.

Just to note that the date column is a string not in datetime format.

Is there something I am doing wrong with the query?

```
Select *
FROM table1
WHERE docDate between '2023-6-1' to '2023-6-30'
```

Comment: *"Just to note that the date column is a string not in datetime format."* There's your problem. Fix your design, fix the problem. The fact you made such a fundamental mistake is almost certainly why you're getting undesirable behaviour.

Comment: You've also tagged SSIS and SSMS here; how does an ETL service and an IDE-like application fit in here?

Comment: What's the datatype of your date column?  I bet it's varchar.

Comment: The OP stated it is in the question, @Eric .

Comment: You will have to convert the date to a `DATE` before using it in `WHERE`.

Comment: If it really is SQL Server that you are using then you'll need to do a convert, as @Eric points out .... WHERE CONVERT(date, docDate) BETWEEN '2023-06-01' AND '2023-06-30'.  Of course, how readily your "string" dates convert to the "date" datatype is all going to depend on how they are formatted.  Of course, it would be a heck of a lot easier if the column was actually a date/datetime datatype

Comment: Do you expect `2023-6-1` to be greater or less than `2023-12-31`? You really need to fix that column and use a proper data type instead of varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've stumbled upon an issue with date comparison when the dates are stored as strings which it is not very recommended as a best practice.

The issue with your query is the use of the 'between' clause with string dates. Since the dates are strings, the database is performing a lexicographic (alphabetical) comparison, not a date comparison.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    docDate VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, docDate) VALUES
    (1, '2023-06-01'),
    (2, '2023-07-04'),
    (3, '2023-06-05'),
    (4, '2023-06-10'),
    (5, '2023-06-11'),
    (6, '2023-08-15'),
    (7, '2023-06-20'),
    (8, '2023-10-25'),
    (9, '2023-06-27'),
    (10, '2023-06-30');
```

```
10 rows affected
```

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE CAST(docDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2023-06-01' AND '2023-06-30'
```

| id | docDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-01 |
| 3 | 2023-06-05 |
| 4 | 2023-06-10 |
| 5 | 2023-06-11 |
| 7 | 2023-06-20 |
| 9 | 2023-06-27 |
| 10 | 2023-06-30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UrvxhDeZ)

Make sure that the date strings are in the proper format (YYYY-MM-DD) for this conversion to work.